# Adding additional Spring Security method annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

I'm writing a library that uses Spring Security and method security to check whether a user is licensed to perform a certain operation. This is *in addition* to the usual role-based security, and this is causing a problem.

The annotations look like they do in this test class:

```
@RestController
class TestController {

    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
    @Licensed("a")
    public ResponseEntity<String> a() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("a");
    }

    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
    @Licensed("b")
    public ResponseEntity<String> b() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("b");
    }

    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
    @Licensed("c")
    public ResponseEntity<String> c() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("c");
    }
}
```

Having the annotations processed seems simple enough, because you add a `customMethodSecurityDataSource`:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
@Configuration
public class LicenceSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return new LicensedAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource();
    }

    // more configurations
}
```

But the problem is in Spring's implementation:

```
@Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
    DefaultCacheKey cacheKey = new DefaultCacheKey(method, targetClass);
    synchronized (this.attributeCache) {
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> cached = this.attributeCache.get(cacheKey);
        // Check for canonical value indicating there is no config attribute,
        if (cached != null) {
            return cached;
        }
        // No cached value, so query the sources to find a result
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = null;
        for (MethodSecurityMetadataSource s : this.methodSecurityMetadataSources) {
            attributes = s.getAttributes(method, targetClass);
            if (attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // Put it in the cache.
        if (attributes == null || attributes.isEmpty()) {
            this.attributeCache.put(cacheKey, NULL_CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE);
            return NULL_CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE;
        }
        this.logger.debug(LogMessage.format("Caching method [%s] with attributes %s", cacheKey, attributes));
        this.attributeCache.put(cacheKey, attributes);
        return attributes;
    }
```

My custom metadata source is processed first, and as soon as it finds an annotation that it recognises, it stops processing. Specifically, in this if-block:

```
if (attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty()) {
    break;
}
```

The result is that my `LicenceDecisionVoter` votes to abstain; after all, there could be other annotation processors that check roles. And because there are no more attributes to vote upon, only `ACCESS_ABSTAIN` is returned, and as per Spring's default and recommended configuration, access is denied. The roles are never checked.

Do I have an alternative, other than to implement scanning for Spring's own annotation processors, like the `@Secured` and JSR-250 annotations?

Or was the mistake to use Spring Security in the first place for this specific purpose?

Comment: Just to clarify - why don't you use `@PreAuthorize`/`@PostAuthorize`?

Comment: Because I reckoned that any licensing question can be reduced to a boolean, and as such, you only need a label. So if the licence allows 40 users, you need to check `isAllowedToAddUser`, or something of the sort. However, `@Preauthorize` would not solve the problem, because Spring stops processing once it finds an annotation that it recognises. So I'd have to construct the `@Preauthorize` annotation in such a way that it covers both role-based and licensed access. It would seem... inelegant.

Comment: Write a proper security expression in an `@PreAuthorize` something like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') and @licenseChecker.isLicensed('a')"`. No need for a custom voter (which is advised against nowadays) but use proper expressions.

Comment: My biggest issue with Spring is that the plethora of articles and SO questions don't age well with newer Spring versions. So what is there against custom voters? I'll check the expressions, but it could entail a fundamental rewrite of the code. You know, as soon as you change one thing...

Comment: Why would it entail a rewrite? You already got the logic you need (that is in your Voter). You need just make that voter a bean (and not a real `RoleVoter`) and call the method (which should return a boolean). The biggest case against voters is that they are simplistic. You can write very elaborate security expressions (like ip-address checks, ip-ranges, roles/authorities, etc. etc.) which would be impossible with just voters.

Comment: But the thing is, the licence system *is* simplistic. Either it's licensed or not. As Edsger W. Dijkstra said: “Simplicity is prerequisite for reliability.” What I forgot to mention is that this is a Spring Boot starter, so I'm not going to care about IP addresses. But I've come to the conclusion that I need a separate `MethodInterceptor` bean, because I shouldn't enable `@GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. I'll write an answer once I get that working.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, the solution. It was more work than I imagined, and the code may have issues because it is partly copied from Spring, and some of that code looks dodgy (or at least, IntelliJ thinks it does).

The key is to remove the `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. Leave that to the application itself. The (auto) configuration class looks like the following:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LicenceProperties.class)
@Configuration
@Import(LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisorRegistrar.class)
public class LicenceAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean public <T extends Licence> LicenceChecker<T> licenceChecker(
            @Lazy @Autowired final LicenceProperties properties,
            @Lazy @Autowired final LicenceFactory<T> factory
    ) throws InvalidSignatureException, LicenceExpiredException, WrappedApiException,
             IOException, ParseException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        final LicenceLoader loader = new LicenceLoader(factory.getPublicKey());
        final T licence = loader.load(properties.getLicenceFile(), factory.getType());
        return factory.getChecker(licence);
    }

    @Bean MethodSecurityInterceptor licenceSecurityInterceptor(
            final LicensedMetadataSource metadataSource,
            final LicenceChecker<?> licenceChecker
    ) {
        final MethodSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new MethodSecurityInterceptor();
        interceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(decisionManager(licenceChecker));
        interceptor.setSecurityMetadataSource(metadataSource);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean LicenceAccessDecisionManager decisionManager(@Autowired final LicenceChecker<?> licenceChecker) {
        return new LicenceAccessDecisionManager(licenceChecker);
    }

    @Bean LicensedMetadataSource licensedMetadataSource() {
        return new LicensedMetadataSource();
    }
}
```

The registrar:

```
public class LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisorRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(final AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata,
                                        final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        final BeanDefinitionBuilder advisor = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                .rootBeanDefinition(LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisor.class);
        advisor.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        advisor.addConstructorArgReference("licensedMetadataSource");
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("licensedMetadataSourceAdvisor", advisor.getBeanDefinition());
    }
}
```

And finally, the advisor:

```
public class LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisor extends AbstractPointcutAdvisor implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private final LicenceMetadataSourcePointcut pointcut = new LicenceMetadataSourcePointcut();

    private transient LicensedMetadataSource attributeSource;

    private transient BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private transient MethodInterceptor interceptor;

    private transient volatile Object adviceMonitor = new Object();

    public LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisor(final LicensedMetadataSource attributeSource) {
        this.attributeSource = attributeSource;
    }

    @Override public void setBeanFactory(final BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override public Pointcut getPointcut() {
        return pointcut;
    }

    @Override public Advice getAdvice() {
        synchronized (this.adviceMonitor) {
            if (this.interceptor == null) {
                Assert.state(this.beanFactory != null, "BeanFactory must be set to resolve 'adviceBeanName'");
                this.interceptor = this.beanFactory.getBean("licenceSecurityInterceptor", MethodInterceptor.class);
            }
            return this.interceptor;
        }
    }

    class LicenceMetadataSourcePointcut extends StaticMethodMatcherPointcut implements Serializable {

        @Override public boolean matches(final Method method, final Class<?> targetClass) {
            final LicensedMetadataSource source = LicensedMetadataSourceAdvisor.this.attributeSource;
            final Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = source.getAttributes(method, targetClass);
            return attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

The latter two classes are copied and modified from Spring. The advisor was copied from `MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor`, and that's a class that somebody at Spring might have a look at, because of the `transient volatile` synchronisation object (which I copied, because I can't yet establish if it should be `final` instead), and because it has a private method that is never used.